# "Узнайте как получить". Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Нужна ли запятая в предложении "**Узнайте как получить**"? Мне хочется поставить, но не могу найти правило.

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь:

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm

> Запятой отделяются также неполные или близкие к неполным придаточные
>   предложения. Исключения:
>
> - придаточное предложение состоит из одного только союзного слова; ср. "**Узнайте как.**";
> - перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит отрицание *не*;
> - перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит сочинительный союз (обычно повторяющийся) и, или, либо и т.п.

Здесь такого нет, поэтому запятая **нужна**.